Image Tool: uploading failed because of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'success')
I am building a simple blogging website and was trying to implement image tool of editor.js but got this error. I am using typescript and react.
Error I am encountering.
Image Tool: uploading failed because of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'success')
    at _P.onUpload (image.mjs:1118:7)
    at B.onUpload (image.mjs:931:29)
    at image.mjs:771:12

Image config tool
image:{
        class:ImageTool,
        config:{
            uploader:{
                async uploadByFile(file:any){
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("file",file);
                    const resp = await axios.post(
                        `http://192.168.1.227:5000/api/blog-image`,
                        formData,{
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': `${authKey}`
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    if(resp.data.success === 1){
                        return resp.data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

on success the resp.data looks like this
{
  "data": {
    "success": 1,
    "file": {
      "url": "D:\\Y-3\\AD\\Group\\BisleriumBlogs\\BisleriumBlogs\\Public/Images/Rectangle 2852.png"
    }
  },
  "message": "Blog image added successfully!"
}

How to solve this??
I tried to sending the return manually. But couldn't figure out at all.

"on success the resp.data looks like this" - The error indicates otherwise.  How specifically are you observing this?

Does resp.data.data.success === 1 instead of resp.data.success === 1 help?

@David i got the response when i manually upload the file.

@NischalBohara: What specifically do you mean by that?  What specific debugging have you done?

So it says your structure is not matching, try using resp.data.data.success === 1

The error indicates that resp.data is undefined, so this would produce the same error
(albeit for a different subsequent property) for the same reason.

This won't solve the problem.
